# Share dest between positional arguments and options

Tags: python, argparse

I have this very simple `ArgumentParser` instance, with an optional positional argument and an option, which writes a constant to the same destination:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', action='store_const', dest='path', const='<all>')
parser.add_argument('path', nargs='?')

# Prints None instead of '<all>'
print(parser.parse_args(['-a']).path)
```

But no matter what, parsing the command line `['-a']` does not yield a `Namespace` instance with `path` set to that constant. Instead, the default from the positional argument is used.

What am I doing wrong?

My use case is that the user should be able to specify a path (actually a list of paths). This list of paths defaults to the current working directory. But instead of using that default, `-a` can be passed, which should result in some configured root directory to be used. The full code for this part of the argument parser is this:

```
all_sentinel = object()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
paths_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
paths_group.add_argument('-a', action='store_const', dest='paths', const=all_sentinel)
paths_group.add_argument('paths', nargs='*', default=['.'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A positional with `nargs='?'` has some special handling of its default (here `None`).

Normally defaults are assigned to the Namespace at the start of parsing, and overwritten by the actions, such as the optional.

Because an empty list of values satisfies the `nargs`, that positional is always 'seen'.  But rather than assign `[]` or some other 'blank' to it, the parser assigns the default.  So the positional's default overwrites the value set by '-a'.

`nargs='*'` gets the same kind of special handling.

I suspect that if you had another positional argument before the '-a', that you wouldn't see this effect.  The '?*' positional would be processed before the '-a', and not overwrite its value.

Optionals are only processed if the flag occurs.  Positionals are always processed, regardless of the `nargs`.  The 'optional' positionals are processed, but with some extra handling of the defaults.  But when they are processed relative to flagged arguments can vary.

That's some tricky behavior that I'm aware of simply because I've studied the code in detail, and answered a lot questions here and on the Python bug/issues.

Sharing the `dest` often does work, but that's more by default than design.  It's the result of other design choices.  `argparse` makes no promises in that regard.   So if it isn't reliable, don't use it.

Comment: Oh, good to know. I did kind of expect this to be supported. I probably came to this conclusion because the positional argument and the option were actually part of the same _mutually exclusive group_ (I've updated the question) and thus I expected the definition of the argument to not have an effect on the result when the option is used. But on second thought, it makes sense that the default of the argument is still inserted into the namespace, sadly overwriting my value. Well, not too bad. I'm still impressed how far `argparse` goes in making writing command line tools fun! :)

Comment: A mutually_exclusive_group doesn't change the handling of the `dest`.  The group testing uses a `seen_non_default_actions` set, which is different from the `seen_actions` set, in its handling of these non-required positionals.